# Select one value of column, corresponding with distinct value of other column

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

```
voucherId   value  balance
   1         100    20
   2         300    120
   3         500    220

orderId   voucherId  ordertouserId
   1         1           1
   2         3           2   
   3         2           1
   4         1           1  
   2         2           2
```

I have two tables vouchers and orders. I want to

```
select sum(value)
from vouchers with distinct orderid
group by ordertouserId
```

I'm not sure how I can do this.

This query:

```
select o.ordertouserId, count(o.order_id) as Orders, sum(v.value) as Total_value
from vouchers v
join orders o on o.voucher_id = v.voucher_id
group by o.ordertouserId
```

Gives the result:

```
ordertouserId  Orders Total_value
 1               3      500   
 2               2      1000
```

But I want to select `sum(v.value)` corresponding to `distinct o.orderId` as `Total_value`.

Desired Result:

```
ordertouserId  Orders Total_value
 1               3      500   
 2               1      500
```

Answer (score 0):

In your desired output, the ordertouserId = 2 shows the Total_value for voucherId = 3.  How did you determine that you don't want to show the Total_value for voucherId = 2?

Sorry, that's not an answer, but I don't have enough "Reputation" to post a comment on the question.  Baring a better understanding of how you selected Total_value = 500 (rather than Total_value = 300) for ordertouserId = 2, my answer would have to be:

The output you desire is not possible to obtain because there is no clear way to determine which voucherId should be used in calculating Total_value where ordertouserId = 2.

BTW, I think there's an error in the first output table which shows ordertouserId = 2 with Total_value = 1000.  Shouldn't the TotalValue for ordertouserId = 2 be 300 + 500 = 800?

Comment: I don't want to show total_value for voucherid=2 because order id of dese two is same. so i want total_value of first order.

Comment: There is not an error it will take value for voucher id 3 twice i.e 500+500 i.e 1000. Please try creating above tables and run query.

Comment: If you want total value of the _first_ order, how is the order determined?  Is it based on which row appears first in the data?  (This might be a somewhat brittle approach since business logic calculations should ideally produce the same result regardless of how the data is ordered in the table).

Comment: Since orderid of these two is same second voucherid would not come into picture distict always select value of first record.

Comment: Err... "distinct" works on columns, not on rows.  It selects values that are the same across multiple rows (and doesn't care about the values of other columns not included in the distinct clause).

Comment: It seems what i am trying to do is not possible. I have to think in other way and apply multiple or subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Per you suggestion in a comment on my other answer, I created the tables and ran the query.  Here's what I have (it's different from the output you have in the question).  BTW, the query you posted also didn't work as provided, there's a mix of camel-case Id and _id in the column names.

I created the tables and ran the query.  Here's the result:

```
mysql> select * from vouchers;
```

```
    +-----------+-------+---------+
    | voucherId | value | balance |
    +-----------+-------+---------+
    |         1 |   100 |      20 |
    |         2 |   300 |     120 |
    |         3 |   500 |     220 |
    +-----------+-------+---------+
    3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> select * from orders;
```

```
    +---------+-----------+---------------+
    | orderId | voucherId | ordertouserId |
    +---------+-----------+---------------+
    |       1 |         1 |             1 |
    |       2 |         3 |             2 |
    |       3 |         2 |             1 |
    |       4 |         1 |             1 |
    |       2 |         2 |             2 |
    +---------+-----------+---------------+
    5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> select o.ordertouserId, count(o.orderId) as Orders, sum(v.value) as Total_value from vouchers v join orders o on o.voucherId=v.voucherId group by o.ordertouserId
```

```
    +---------------+--------+-------------+
    | ordertouserId | Orders | Total_value |
    +---------------+--------+-------------+
    |             1 |      3 |         500 |
    |             2 |      2 |         800 |
    +---------------+--------+-------------+
```